# What does "Warning. Website not www redirected properly" mean?

Tags: redirects

I have an online store directory and have used different online sources to analyze my site. I received the following message:

> Warning. Website not www redirected properly.
>
> Notes: www 301 redirect avoids duplicate content problem which could affect website ranking.

Comment: Is this a message you get from your web browser when you visit your site?  Or is this a warning you get from a diagnostic tool such as Google Search Console?

Comment: It's from a diagnostic tool online (not google)

Comment: Which tool?  Is there an extended message?    Does that tool have help documentation?

Comment: It's "SEO Checker & SEO Analyzer Report" from siteprice(dot)org.

Comment: I see that site in the Google search results when I search for your error message in quotes.      Why are you using that site?   It has horrible grammar.  There is no way I would trust it.

Comment: I have visited many different sites to analyze my website.  I have been trying to figure out why I don't get much traffic. I just thought maybe that's one of the reasons why.  I am sure there are many reasons, but thank you, Stephen, I will definitely disregard that site.

Comment: It isn't just the grammar.   It also has the advice "Website main page doesn't have meta keywords tag."   That is just bogus.   Meta keywords haven't been worthwhile for SEO in over ten years.  It is trying to fetch PageRank for each site even though Google stopped updating those numbers a couple years ago.   It also appears not to be able to measure page sizes well.   I see it reporting "111 bytes" (even though the page is actually normal sized) and then claiming that it is more than 32KB (which isn't a recommended size cut off that should trigger an error anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

I tested a site that had that in its error report on siteprice.org.  I used curl to fetch the site both with and without the `www` on the domain name:

```
$ curl --head http://example.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 18:21:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

$ curl --head http://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 18:21:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The site is not 301 redirecting one to the other.   Rather it is serving the same content on both.  Presumably, you would get the same error if you were using 302 temporary redirects.   You might even get the same error if you were using the meta rel canonical link tag, even though that would be a valid way of fixing the issue.

This has historically been considered an SEO problem.   It caused duplicate content issues and did not utilize the power of all your inbound links.  It was considered best practice to choose one "canonical" www or no-www and redirect the other to it.

These days, Google is much better about dealing with sites that serve the same content on multiple URLs.   I'd still consider it best practice to put the redirect in place (or use the canonical tag), but it is at most a very minor SEO issue.   It is not the reason that your site is not ranking well.

Comment: Well, at least that eliminates one reason! Thanks!